# How to store data coming from a webpage in python django framework

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I want to develop a python django project for online Examination.
I want to know how to save the responses coming from a webpages.

what are the best ways for saving the responses in python django framework.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to save the response would be by using Django's built-in models. Generally, each model maps to a single table in a database. So you'd be storing the data in a database, using Django's models.

Check out the documentation on models here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/

Also, I'd suggest following Django's excellent tutorial. Most of these questions will be answered once you get a basic understanding of how the Django framework works, for which the tutorial is an excellent start. You can find it here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: Thanks for your response.                                            I want to save the responses for questions ie. answers submitted by users how to save them. can i use json, xml or django provides any features for that.

Comment: I assume that the answers would also be submitted into Django? If so, that is exactly what you can do with Django, you can take the user input and enter them into a database using Django's models. That way there would be no need to convert the data to JSON or XML before doing so. You could simply use the string, int or whatever form the user input takes and enter it into a database.

Comment: But, again please check out the tutorial as it covers all this. It describes using user input and creating models (the tutorial takes you through creating a poll using Django).

Comment: how to get the response coming from the web page .can you suggest me anything which help in this regard.

Comment: Absolutely. You should use forms to get user input, and then handle that response.

This page describes how to create a basic form and handle the user input: 

http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07.html